# writing a subset of source ini file into destination ini file

Tags: python, configparser

I have source.ini as following

```
[section1]
name = 'xyz'
place = 'abc'

[section2]
....
....

[section3]
....
....
```

I want to read the source.ini and copy contents of only list of sections into a new ini file. Here's my code doing the needful..

```
import ConfigParser

Config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
Config.read('source.ini')
sections = ['section1', 'section2']

outputConfig = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()

with open('destination.ini', 'wb') as fp:
    for each_section in sections:
        fp.write('\n\n['+each_section+']\n')
        for (each_key, each_val) in Config.items(each_section):
            fp.write(each_key+':'+each_val+'\n')

        outputConfig.write(fp)
```

I'm getting the output as desired. My question is am I doing it the right way? IS there a more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your code is inelegant. It writes the output file **twice**. First, by hand:

```
fp.write(each_key+':'+each_val+'\n')
```

and second, with the help of the `RawConfigParser` object:

```
outputConfig.write(fp)
```

Only the manual write is effective. The call to `outputConfig.write()` is a no-op.

We should eliminate one of the two methods of creating the output file, but which one? I claim the manual method should be removed, since your program otherwise doesn't need to have intimate knowledge of the .INI file format.

Also, I find your use of `each_` to represent loop variables disconcerting. Maybe its just a personal preference.

Here is how I would fix it:

```
import ConfigParser

Config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
Config.read('source.ini')
sections = ['section1', 'section2']

outputConfig = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()

for section in sections:
    outputConfig.add_section(section)
    for key, val in Config.items(section):
        outputConfig.set(section, key, val)


with open('destination.ini', 'w') as fp:
    outputConfig.write(fp)
```

Comment: thanks Rob! that was quick and helpful. Serge's answer is interested too since that takes care of comments not getting stripped out..check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Independantly of the answer of Rob, there may some other problems with your approach. First, you use a `RawConfigParser`. It is correct under Python 2.x, but for 3.x, it is considered as legacy and `ConfigParser` would be recommended.

But IMHO, the main problem is that the `configparser` module will strip any comment from your file if you have some and want to keep them. Here is a variant using regex that will keep comments provided they are either at beginning of file or after a valid `[section]` :

```
import re

sections = ['section1', 'section2']
rxsect = re.compile('^\s*\[\s*(\w+)\s*\]')
with open('source.init') as fin, open('destination.ini', 'w') as fout:
    copy = True
    for line in fin:
        m = rxsect.match(line)
        if m:
            copy = m.group(1) in sections
        if copy:
            n = fout.write(line)
```

Of course, if comments are not a concern, Rob's answer is better because the file is parsed and syntax errors would be detected, while mine assumes the file is syntaxically correct.

Comment: this is brilliant. I didn't think of comments getting stripped out. That is an amazing answer my friend. I have to accept Rob's answer though since that was what I asked for. I wish I could accept two answers :)